# Random values with non-uniform distribution

Tags: php, random

I want a random number generator with non-uniform distribution, ie:

```
// prints 0 with 0.1 probability, and 1 with 0.9 probability
echo probRandom(array(10, 90));
```

This is what I have right now:

```
/**
 * method to generated a *not uniformly* random index
 *
 * @param array $probs int array with weights 
 * @return int a random index in $probs
 */
function probRandom($probs) {
    $size = count($probs);

    // construct probability vector
    $prob_vector = array();
    $ptr = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
        $ptr += $probs[$i]; 
        $prob_vector[$i] = $ptr;
    }

    // get a random number
    $rand = rand(0, $ptr);
    for ($i=0, $ret = false; $ret === false; $i++) {
        if ($rand <= $prob_vector[$i])
            return $i;
    }   
}
```

Can anyone think of a better way? Possibly one that doesn't require me to do pre-processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution you generate an accumulated probability vector, which is very useful.

I have two suggestions for improvement:

- if `$probs` are static, i.e. it's the same vector every time you want to generate a random number, you can preprocess `$prob_vector` just once and keep it.
- you can use binary search for the `$i` (Newton bisection method)

**EDIT:** I now see that you ask for a solution without preprocessing.

Without preprocessing, you will end up with worst case linear runtime (i.e., double the length of the vector, and your running time will double as well).

Here is a method that doesn't require preprocessing. It does, however, require you to know a maximum limit of the elements in `$probs`:

**Rejection method**

- Pick a random index, `$i` and a random number, `X` (uniformly) between `0` and `max($probs)-1`, inclusive.
- If `X` is less than `$probs[$i]`, you're done - `$i` is your random number
- Otherwise **reject** `$i` (hence the name of the method) and restart.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the sum of all elements in  `$probs`, you can do this without preprocessing.

Like so:

```
$max = sum($probs);
$r = rand(0,$max-1);
$tot = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < length($probs); $i++) {
    $tot += $probs[$i];
    if ($r < $tot) {
        return $i;
    }
}
```

This will do what you want in O(N) time, where N is the length of the array.  This is a firm lower bound on the algorithmic runtime of such an algorithm, as each element in the input must be considered.

The probability a given index `$i` is selected is `$probs[$i]/sum($probs)`, given that the `rand` function returns independent uniformly distributed integers in the given range.

Comment: This is a silly question, but I wonder if sorting $probs array does any good to the results of the algorithm?

Comment: @ramayac: yes, putting the larger elements first would improve this algorithm's performance, but unless the array is already sorted or you're running this multiple times you would lose out. This is O(N) and sorting is going to be more effort.