# "Reverse" statistics: generating data based on mean and standard deviation

Tags: language-agnostic, statistics

Having a dataset and calculating statistics from it is easy. How about the other way around?

Let's say I know some variable has an average X, standard deviation Y and assume it has normal (Gaussian) distribution. What would be the best way to generate a "random" dataset (of arbitrary size) which will fit the distribution?

EDIT: This kind of develops from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207272/random-values-with-non-uniform-distribution); I could make something based on that method, but I am wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can generate **standard** normal random variables with the [Box-Mueller method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_M%C3%BCller).  Then to transform that to have mean mu and standard deviation sigma, multiply your samples by sigma and add mu.  I.e. for each z from the standard normal, return mu + sigma*z.

Answer (score 9):

This is really easy to do in Excel with the norminv() function. Example:

=norminv(rand(), 100, 15)

would generate a value from a normal distribution with mean of 100 and stdev of 15 (human IQs). Drag this formula down a column and you have as many values as you want.

Answer (score 3):

I found a page where this problem is solved in several programming languages:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Random_numbers

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to generate Gaussian random variables.  The standard method is Box-Meuller which was mentioned earlier.  A slightly faster version is here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm

Here's the wikipedia reference on generating Gaussian variables

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution

Answer (score 2):

I'll give an example using [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and the 2nd algorithm in the list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution).

```
X<-4; Y<-2 # mean and std
z <- sapply(rep(0,100000), function(x) (sum(runif(12)) - 6) * Y + X)

plot(density(z))
> mean(z)
[1] 4.002347

> sd(z)
[1] 2.005114

> library(fUtilities)

> skewness(z,method ="moment")
[1] -0.003924771
attr(,"method")
[1] "moment"

> kurtosis(z,method ="moment")
[1] 2.882696
attr(,"method")
[1] "moment"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a kind of Monte Carlo simulation. Start with a wide random "acceptable range" and generate a few truly random values. Check your statistics and see if the average and variance are off. Adjust the "acceptable range" for the random values and add a few more values. Repeat until you have hit both your requirements and your population sample size.

Just off the top of my head, let me know what you think. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB function [`normrnd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html) from the Statistics Toolbox can generate normally distributed random numbers with a given mu and sigma.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to generate dataset with normal distribution (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform ).
Remember that generated sample will not have exact N(0,1) distribution! You need to standarize it - substract mean and then divide by std deviation. Then You are free to transform this sample to Normal distribution with given parameters: multiply by std deviation and then add mean.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly numpy has a prebuilt function for that:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_dataset(mean, std, samples):
    dataset = np.random.normal(mean, std, samples)
    return dataset
```