# Is there a function to determine dataset (discrete scale, 1 to 5) if number of data points, mean, and standard deviation is known?

Tags: function, statistics, language-agnostic

My question is very similar to this question: ["Reverse" statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208299/reverse-statistics-generating-data-based-on-mean-and-standard-deviation). They, however, want to create a *normal* (and random) distribution of *arbitrary* size that fits a certain mean and standard deviation. Let's say, however, that we know *more than* the mean and std. deviation, that we know the **number of data points** as well as the **discrete scale** the values fall on.

So I really have two questions. **First**, given we know,

- mean
- standard deviation
- n
- discrete scale of 1 to 5 (i.e., values can only be 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5)

...is it possible to know the exact dataset? For example, if we know that there are 5 data points on a 1–5 Likert scale, and the mean is 4.40 and the standard deviation is 1.20, is it possible to figure out that the data set is {5, 5, 5, 5, 2} (order of values not being important)?

**Second**, is there a function already out there to automatically solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data sets I am trying to identify are fairly small (n < 30), a friend of mine suggested using `itertools` `combinations_with_replacement()` to generate all possible data sets and then write a matching function given my parameters.

Here's the final code.

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from statistics import pstdev

# Function to figure out exact data set given we know:
## N is integer (number of data points)
## SIGMA is float (standard deviation)
## MU is float (mean)
## discreteScale is list (all possible values of data points)
#### Function returns list containing tuple(s) (possible sets of data points that match criteria)

def find_DataSet(N, MU, SIGMA, discreteScale):
    possibleCombs = combinations_with_replacement(discreteScale, N)
    
    container = []
    for dataSet in possibleCombs:
        mu = sum(dataSet)/len(dataSet)
        roundMu = round(mu, 2)
        
        sigma = pstdev(dataSet)
        roundSigma = round(sigma, 2)
        
        if ((roundMu == MU) and (roundSigma == SIGMA)):
            container.append(dataSet)
        
    return container
```

Example Output:

```py
result = find_DataSet(20, 4.50, 0.81, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(result)
```

[(2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), (3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)]